# unit text mock dbContext

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, moq

I try to do a unitary test on a repository that returns a Ienumerable. But I have the next mistake:

```
  System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. (The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<myNamespace.DTO.UserDTO>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.)
    ---- System.InvalidOperationException : The source IQueryable doesn't implement IAsyncEnumerable<myNamespace.DTO.UserDTO>. Only sources that implement IAsyncEnumerable can be used for Entity Framework asynchronous operations.
```

This my unit test :

```
            //Arrange
            var mockSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<User>, IQueryable<User>, IDbAsyncEnumerable<User>>();

            ((IDbAsyncEnumerable<User>)mockSet).GetAsyncEnumerator()
               .Returns(new TestDbAsyncEnumerator<User>(GetUserList().AsQueryable().GetEnumerator()));
            ((IQueryable<User>)mockSet).Provider.Returns(new TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<User>(GetUserList().AsQueryable().Provider));
            ((IQueryable<User>)mockSet).Expression.Returns(GetUserList().AsQueryable().Expression);
            ((IQueryable<User>)mockSet).ElementType.Returns(GetUserList().AsQueryable().ElementType);
            ((IQueryable<User>)mockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(GetUserList().AsQueryable().GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = Substitute.For<IMyContext>();
            mockContext.Users.Returns(mockSet);

            //Act 
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            UserRepository userRepository = new UserRepository(mockContext);
            var users = userRepository.GetListAsync(cancellationToken).Result;

            //Assert  
            Assert.NotNull(users);
```

My repo I want to test :

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetListAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await _myContext.Users.Select(u => new UserDto
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        FistName = u.FistName ,
        LastName = u.LastName 
    }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: Well, whatever `GetListAsync` is doing, it's not working with an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` which it wants for the async operation. Are you using `dbContext.Users` or `dbContext.Set<UserDTO>()` to access the set? Usually my advice is mocking efcore is hard and in this case where you need async operations, to use one of the testing libraries out there. My library EntityFrameworkCore.Testing is one of them.

Comment: I have updated my question. I want to test my repository which returns a Userdto list

Comment: Right, so the problem is probably the provider. What does that look like?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: At a guess, ToListAsync will create or execute a query against the db set provider. That provider will be TestDbAsyncQueryProvider<User>. You need to provide minimum reproducible code for us to help you, you're only giving us half the code.

Comment: I followed the following link with asynchronous method tests. But instead of returning my entity, my repository returns a DTO
 : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking

Comment: @ddd you don't need to mock the DbContext in EF Core. You can configure it to use [an in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) or even an in-memory Sqlite instance

Comment: The article you link to is for EF6, not EF Core. You're essentially rebuilding the DbContext class using mocks. This means that instead of testing your repository, you end up testing your mocking code.

Comment: The in-memory provider won't work for async ops

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: @ddd There is a tiny but really powerful Moq mocking contrib for DbContext. It is called [EntityFrameworkCore3Mock](https://github.com/huysentruitw/entity-framework-core3-mock). I encourage you to give it us, it helped us a lot to test our repository layer and remain concise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As covered in the OP comments the doco you're referring to is for EF, not EFCore. You need to implement a different set of interfaces.

The usual advice is to avoid mocking the `DbContext` however in this case you probably need to as the async operations aren't supported by the in-memory provider. I'm not sure if SQLite supports them. [EntityFrameworkCore.Testing](https://github.com/rgvlee/EntityFrameworkCore.Testing) should handle this case (disclaimer, I am the author), but you'd need to use your context implementation rather than an interface.

The most common way to get this working is to create implementations of the async interfaces, in the same manner as the EF doco but for EFCore. You'll find most EFCore mocking libraries will do it this way:

```
public class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _queryable;

    public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerable = enumerable;

        _queryable = _enumerable.AsQueryable();

        ElementType = _queryable.ElementType;
        Expression = _queryable.Expression;
        Provider = new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(_queryable);
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(_queryable);
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType { get; }
    public Expression Expression { get; }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

    public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        return new ValueTask();
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        return new ValueTask<bool>(_enumerator.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current => _enumerator.Current;
}

public class TestAsyncQueryProvider<T> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    public TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    private IQueryable<T> Source { get; }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(Source.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This isn't a complete implementation, just what's needed to solve the OP case. The important bit is this line:

```
public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
{
    return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(Source.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression));
}
```

This is what is going to allow the projection to work with the async operation.

Working example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoFixture;
using KellermanSoftware.CompareNetObjects;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal;
using NSubstitute;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Question62783423
{
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture();

            var users = new TestAsyncEnumerable<User>(fixture.CreateMany<User>());

            //Arrange
            var mockSet = Substitute.For<DbSet<User>, IQueryable<User>, IAsyncEnumerable<User>>();

            ((IAsyncEnumerable<User>) mockSet).GetAsyncEnumerator().Returns(users.GetAsyncEnumerator());
            ((IQueryable<User>) mockSet).Provider.Returns(users.Provider);
            ((IQueryable<User>) mockSet).Expression.Returns(users.Expression);
            ((IQueryable<User>) mockSet).ElementType.Returns(users.ElementType);
            ((IQueryable<User>) mockSet).GetEnumerator().Returns(((IQueryable<User>) users).GetEnumerator());

            var mockContext = Substitute.For<IMyContext>();
            mockContext.Users.Returns(mockSet);

            //Act 
            var cancellationToken = new CancellationToken();
            var userRepository = new UserRepository(mockContext);
            var result1 = userRepository.GetListAsync(cancellationToken).Result;
            var result2 = userRepository.GetListAsync(cancellationToken).Result;

            var comparer = new CompareLogic();
            comparer.Config.IgnoreCollectionOrder = true;
            comparer.Config.IgnoreObjectTypes = true;
            var comparisonResult1 = comparer.Compare(users, result1);
            var comparisonResult2 = comparer.Compare(users, result2);

            Assert.That(comparisonResult1.Differences.Any(), Is.False);
            Assert.That(comparisonResult2.Differences.Any(), Is.False);
        }
    }
}

public class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;
    private readonly IQueryable<T> _queryable;

    public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerable = enumerable;

        _queryable = _enumerable.AsQueryable();

        ElementType = _queryable.ElementType;
        Expression = _queryable.Expression;
        Provider = new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(_queryable);
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(_queryable);
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public Type ElementType { get; }
    public Expression Expression { get; }
    public IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _enumerator;

    public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        _enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        return new ValueTask();
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync()
    {
        return new ValueTask<bool>(_enumerator.MoveNext());
    }

    public T Current => _enumerator.Current;
}

public class TestAsyncQueryProvider<T> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    public TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryable<T> source)
    {
        Source = source;
    }

    private IQueryable<T> Source { get; }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(Source.Provider.CreateQuery<TElement>(expression));
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IMyContext
{
    DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class UserRepository
{
    private readonly IMyContext _myContext;

    public UserRepository(IMyContext myContext)
    {
        _myContext = myContext;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDto>> GetListAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _myContext.Users.Select(u => new UserDto { Id = u.Id, FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName = u.LastName }).ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using EF. I've updated the answer with an EFCore example.